# Dropping any arguments from a string representing a command line in bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I need to write a bash function which, given a string that represents a command line, returns just the first token in the command line (i.e. the program being called, **which may have spaces in its name**), dropping any arguments. I want to do this **without** using `sed` or `awk` or anything but bash builtins and variable manipulation.

e.g.:

```
drop_args "ls" # prints "ls"
drop_args "ls -al" # prints "ls"
drop_args "spaces\ in\ name --bad-idea" # prints "spaces\ in\ name"
```

What I've tried is:

```
drop_args () { echo $1; }
```

and then I call `drop_args ls -al`, i.e. without quoting the string, and that works nicely for all cases that I can see except for `drop_args spaces\ in\ name`.

I'm not too terribly concerned if I can't do this in a way that correctly handles the spaces case with the restrictions I have stipulated, but I need to at least reliably detect that situation and display an appropriate error message, I guess.

This is related to my earlier question about [dereferencing shell aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180906/programmatically-dereference-resolve-aliases-in-bash); it's sort of a subproblem of what I am ultimately trying to accomplish there.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your function. It handles `spaces\ in\ name` without quotes nicely

Comment: hmmm.  Not sure what the problem is.  I created a script: "do it.sh".  The content of the script was simply "echo $0".  When I ran it, it echod "do it.sh".  Is this not what you were looking for?

Comment: @perreal Hmm, you're right that it does appear to work fine from the command line:
    `$ drop_args A\ Bad\ Program --terrible`
    returns `A Bad Program`
...but when called from within a shell script, I guess escaped spaces behave differently and it returns `A\\`. I need it to work within a script.

Comment: What's with the double quotes in your examples? I would expect `drop_args "foo bar"` to print `foo bar` and `drop_args foo bar` to print `foo`.

Comment: @tripleee it seems not to matter in the context of a script; `\ `  (backslash-space) just doesn't parse the way I want it to

Answer (score 0):

```
drop_args()
{
  read cmd args <<< "$1"
  echo "$cmd"
}
```

This loses the backslashes, but they were never really meant to be "there" in the first place.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work properly within a script; the behavior of backslashes in strings is different.

Comment: Why are backslashes being put in arbitrary places?

Comment: What do you mean? They're there to "escape" the spaces as they might be escaped on the command line.

Comment: They're only escaped on the command line because the shell will split by words instead. This code makes sure it isn't split. Why do you believe that you still need them?

Comment: Because my program needs to parse the output of `alias`, which displays the values of aliases as they might be entered on the command line. (Why it needs to do this is not relevant or interesting.)

Comment: You already have the command so I don't know why you'd want to, but you could always replace the backslashes back in if you like.

Comment: I already have the command as it appears in the value of an alias, possibly with arguments, and from this string, which contains `A\ Bad\ Program --really-bad --why`, I need to pull out either `A\ Bad\ Program` or `A Bad Program`, don't care which.